# AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect returning correct image but wrong size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am new to iOS Swift development but even newer to manipulating images.  I have a UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView.  I want a user to zoom/pan to show the exact image they want to capture. I have this working to an extent.  When the user clicks a button, it does properly capture the image and exactly what was in the UIScrollView box, however, the SIZE of the image is not correct.  Any help would be appreciated!!

```
@IBAction func tapSendtoBand(sender: UIButton) {


    var frameInfo = frameForImage(photoImageView.image!, imageView: photoImageView)
    var imageWidth = photoImageView.image!.size.height
    var scale:CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0) / (photoImageView.frame.size.height / imageWidth)


    var visibleRect = CGRect()
    var pWidth  = CGFloat(CGImageGetWidth(photoImageView.image?.CGImage))
    var pHeight = CGFloat(CGImageGetHeight(photoImageView.image?.CGImage))


    visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size
    visibleRect.origin.x *= scale
    visibleRect.origin.y *= scale
    visibleRect.size.width *= scale
    visibleRect.size.height *= scale

    var pSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: visibleRect.size.width,height: visibleRect.size.height)


    let bRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(pSize, visibleRect)

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cropImage(photoImageView.image!, rect: bRect), nil, nil, nil)

    photoTest.image = cropImage(photoImageView.image!, rect: bRect)

}
```

Here is the frame function I am using to try to determine the sizing

```
func frameForImage (image:UIImage, imageView:UIImageView) -> CGRect{

        var imageRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        var viewRatio = imageView.frame.size.width / imageView.frame.size.height;

        if(imageRatio < viewRatio){

            var scale = imageView.frame.size.height / image.size.height;

            var width = scale * image.size.width;

            var topLeftX = (imageView.frame.size.width - width) * 0.5;
            return CGRectMake(topLeftX, 0, width, imageView.frame.size.height)
        }
        else{
            var scale = imageView.frame.size.width / image.size.width;
            var height = scale * image.size.height;
            var topLeftY = (imageView.frame.size.height - height) * 0.5;

            return CGRectMake(0, topLeftY, imageView.frame.size.width, height);
        }
    }
```

Here is the function that I use to actually crop the image

```
func cropImage(srcImage:UIImage,rect:CGRect) -> UIImage
{
    var cgImageConv = srcImage.CGImage
    var cgSizeConv:CGSize = CGSize(width: 310,height: 102)
    var cr:CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgImageConv, rect)
    var cropped:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cr)!

    return cropped
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? So the image taken is actually the right part of the original image but the resolution is wrong? Aspect ratio right or wrong? Image size just the double size or half the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the problem.  It was in my approach.  Using my code for the visible area that I wanted to capture, I was able to use the following code to get the exact size I wanted in the correct scale.

```
var cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgImageConv, visibleRect)
        var cfUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cr)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 620, height: 204))
            var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, 102);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), 310, 102), cr);
            var scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        photoTest.image = scaledImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(scaledImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below sets the mode for your image view to aspect ratio and to fill area of screen.

```
//Makes your image view fill the real estate you have available on your phones screen
yourUIImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
```

\

```
//Will make your image view Aspect ratio
yourUIImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 Solution about the previos post here:

```
func frameForImageInImageViewAspectFit(imageView : UIImageView) -> CGRect {
    let img = imageView.image
    let frame = imageView.frame

    let imageRatio = (img?.size.width)! / (img?.size.height)!;
    let viewRatio = frame.size.width / frame.size.height;

    if (imageRatio < viewRatio) {
        let scale = frame.size.height / (img?.size.height)!;

        let width = scale * (img?.size.width)!;

        let topLeftX = (frame.size.width - width) * 0.5;

        return CGRect(x: topLeftX, y: 0, width: width, height: frame.size.height)
    }
    else {
        let scale = frame.size.width / (img?.size.width)!;

        let height = scale * (img?.size.height)!;

        let topLeftY = (frame.size.height - height) * 0.5;

        return CGRect(x: 0, y: topLeftY, width: frame.size.width, height: height)
    }
}
```

But a BETTER solution is (Swift 3):

```
self.imageView.frame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (self.imageView.image?.size)!, insideRect: self.imageView.frame)
```